# operating system - where is long term scheduler used?

Tags: process, operating-system, scheduling, scheduler, job-scheduling

I understand that long term scheduling decides the degree of multi-programming, but I am unable to understand where it can be used. Because let say I want to run some process and double click that icon, now that process has to be loaded into main memory and run. OS never says that it wont run that process.

Can someone please explain a scenario where long term scheduler can be used ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Long Term Scheduling is needed for systems that indeed run long term. Your desktop is not a long term running machine. You use it for some time and then shut it (or leave it idle).

- Even if you leave your machine turned on for months at a time, your jobs are still not the kind that require long term scheduling. They usually end in a short term.
- Further, *even if* you are one of those who start a program and never bother to close it, your machine usually have enough RAM at its disposal to not need long term scheduling. Swapping programs in and out of memory is the job of mid-term scheduler.
- With GBs at OS's disposal, the need for interactivity and the programs which usually don't add up to the entire RAM, long term scheduling is not needed for the kind of programs that are run on a desktop.

Answer (score 1):

"Long term scheduler" is an academic concept. As the phrase is normally used, it relates to batch jobs. As such, there would not be a long term scheduler in an interactive system.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence "long term scheduling decides the degree of multi-programming" means that the number of processes running concurrently in the system is controlled by long term scheduler.

The LT scheduler chooses from the list of processes in "New" state (so, these aren't actually loaded in memory) and puts them in "Ready" state (so, loads them in memory) based on the current load on system and actual capacity of the system.

It always runs when a new process is created from a program.

Its called LT scheduler because of the relative frequency with which it runs compared to MT and ST schedulers.